Tikz: Placing connecting Labels
I'm building a tree n Tikz.  When I assign a label and arrow to show the relationship between two nodes, the label & arrow does not align with the line connecting the two nodes.
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\tikzset{
  every node/.style={   align=center}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{level 1}=[sibling distance=25mm]
    \node[ rectangle, draw, color=red] (MD) {Title}
        [child anchor=north]    
        child  {node (Inv) {SubTitle}  }
        child  {node (Sel) {SecTitle}  };
\draw[<->, thick, blue] (MD) -- node[above, sloped] {abcde} +(Inv);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

My output:

Any suggestions, please?
This was the only search return that was close but didn't have the original lines to align with:
Enhancing Line Connections and Text Alignment in TikZ Diagram

The key child anchor=north that you set draws edges “to” the north anchor point of the child nodes. If you change
\draw[<->, thick, blue] (MD) -- node[above, sloped] {abcde} +(Inv);

to
\draw[<->, thick, blue] (MD) -- node[above, sloped] {abcde} +(Inv.north);

the two lines will match up.

For drawing your tree I would use forest package:
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}


\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
for tree = {
  if level = {0}{draw, red}{},
     l sep = 12mm,
     s sep = 4mm,
      edge = {Straight Barb-Straight Barb, blue},
 EL/.style = {edge label={node[midway, font=\small, inner sep=1pt, anchor=south, sloped]{#1}},},
            }
[Title
    [SubTitle, EL={abcde}]
    [SecTitle] 
]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}


